# How to control the transition of multiples linear-gradients?

Tags: html, css

Lets say we have:

```
.el {
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom, black, black), linear-gradient(to bottom, red, red), linear-gradient(to bottom, blue, blue), linear-gradient(to bottom, green, green);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:0 0;
  background-size:100% 0;
}

.el:hoover{
 background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

How to control the transition of each linear-gradient? lets say.... 500ms 800ms 1s 1.5s?

Without another `div` / `::before` / `::after` is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, the transition applies to the whole property you set. If you have different elements, you can add individual transitions.

Comment: No you can't do this directly but there could be other ways which can be thought of only if we know the real *need* instead of a simplified code that doesn't actually show what you need. For example, here none of the gradients have transparency and so only the topmost layer (which is the first from left) will show up when the size is 100%. So if the timing is shorter for 1st then there is absolutely no chance that the other layers will show up even if different transition time for each gradient was possible.